# Emacs, ruby: convert do end block to curly braces and vice versa

Tags: ruby, emacs

I often find myself converting code like this:

```
before do 
  :something
end
```

to

```
before { :something }
```

Is there a way to automate this task in emacs? I use ruby-mode and rinary, but they're not too helpful here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ruby-mode` in Emacs 24.3 and newer has the command `ruby-toggle-block`.

The default binding is `C-c {`.

Answer (score 5):

I am sure it can be made shorter and better, but for now I've got the following:

```lisp
(defun ruby-get-containing-block ()
  (let ((pos (point))
        (block nil))
    (save-match-data
      (save-excursion
        (catch 'break
          ;; If in the middle of or at end of do, go back until at start
          (while (and (not (looking-at "do"))
                      (string-equal (word-at-point) "do"))
            (backward-char 1))
          ;; Keep searching for the containing block (i.e. the block that begins
          ;; before our point, and ends after it)
          (while (not block)
            (if (looking-at "do\\|{")
                (let ((start (point)))
                  (ruby-forward-sexp)
                  (if (> (point) pos)
                      (setq block (cons start (point)))
                    (goto-char start))))
            (if (not (search-backward-regexp "do\\|{" (point-min) t))
                (throw 'break nil))))))
        block))

(defun ruby-goto-containing-block-start ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((block (ruby-get-containing-block)))
    (if block
        (goto-char (car block)))))

(defun ruby-flip-containing-block-type ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((block (ruby-get-containing-block)))
      (goto-char (car block))
      (save-match-data
        (let ((strings (if (looking-at "do")
                           (cons
                            (if (= 3 (count-lines (car block) (cdr block)))
                                "do\\( *|[^|]+|\\)? *\n *\\(.*?\\) *\n *end"
                              "do\\( *|[^|]+|\\)? *\\(\\(.*\n?\\)+\\) *end")
                            "{\\1 \\2 }")
                         (cons
                          "{\\( *|[^|]+|\\)? *\\(\\(.*\n?\\)+\\) *}"
                          (if (= 1 (count-lines (car block) (cdr block)))
                              "do\\1\n\\2\nend"
                            "do\\1\\2end")))))
          (when (re-search-forward (car strings) (cdr block) t)
            (replace-match (cdr strings) t)
            (delete-trailing-whitespace (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
            (indent-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))))))))
```

There are two functions to be bound to keys: `ruby-goto-containing-block-start` and `ruby-flip-containing-block-type`.

Either command works anywhere inside a block, and hopefully they can skip blocks that should be skipped - although that shouldn't be an issue if you are converting to a short block format.

The `ruby-flip-containing-block-type` collapses three line do .. end blocks to single line {} and vice versa. If the blocks are not exactly 3 lines and 1 line long, it should leave them alone.

I am using this on my ruby setup now, so I would appreciate improvements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression that crosses newlines.

/do(C-q C-j\?)*(.*)(C-q C-j\?)*end/

and replace with

```
{\2 }
```

Something like that could work. You could then customize it until it does exactly what you need and bind it to a macro so that you can whip it out and impress your friends anytime!

I tested the above regexes in vi (my editor of choice) and they worked. So something similar should work for you.

For more information, make sure to checkout the [emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression)!

Comment: Nice. The only thing to note is that in Emacs you need to put C-q C-J in the Regex instead of \n to match new lines :)

Comment: Ha! Thanks man (I'm a vim user so I'm not sure about that stuff... I'll look up the syntax and amend my answer).

Comment: Does this work recursively? I'm unfamiliar with emacs's regex support.

Comment: Works when used with replace-regexp or query-replace-regexp, but what I'm looking for is navigating to the start of the block, hit a key and have that block converted to do.. end. BTW I'm asking this as I'm envious of my Vi- and RubyMine-addicted colleagues who enjoy this function.

And this is approximately 76th time when I promise myself to leard lisp :(

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/1086270) is a function. I am an elisp beginner. It only goes one way; from do to {. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: messes up the entire file. But at least I got an idea how to do it, thanks

Comment: @iosadchii Feel free to add your solution as an answer here, and accept it. I may want to "get inspired" by it.