# Losing cursor location with save-excursion after replace-match

Tags: emacs, elisp

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712076/emacs-ruby-convert-do-end-block-to-curly-braces-and-vice-versa/6769450#6769450), I use a regular expression search/replace to convert from one type of ruby block to another. However, after the function `ruby-flip-containing-block-type` is done, the point is moved to the beginning of the replaced text, even though there is a `save-excursion` around the function.

I even tried saving the point to a register and jumping back to it after the flip. The saved point is relocated to the beginning of my changes. After some google searches, I think the problem lies with the fact that the replace-match call updates the buffer contents at the original point.

Any ideas on how I can preserve/restore the original location of the point in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When text is replaced, the old text is removed, and the new text inserted. So let's say the buffer looks like this, where `-!-` indicates the position of point:

```
abcdefghijklm-!-nopqrstuvwxyz
```

Suppose you replace `jklmnop` with `jlkMnop`. First the `jklmnop` is removed:

```
abcdefghi-!-qrstuvwxyz
```

and then the `jlkMnop` is inserted:

```
abcdefghi-!-jklMnopqrstuvwxyz
```

You can see that the effect is as if point was moved.

The way to preserve point is to be much more careful about how you go about replacing the text. Instead of replacing big blocks (which might well contain point), replace only the small sections that actually change. In the answer you link to, instead of replacing `do\(.*\)end` with `{\1}`, replace the `do` with `{` and the `end` with `}` in separate replacements.

---

This doesn't have to be ugly. Perhaps something like this, using the fifth (`subexp`) argument to [`replace-match`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Replacing-Match.html#Replacing-Match):

```
(when (re-search-forward "\\(do\\).*\\(?:\n.*\\)\\(end\\)" nil t)
  (replace-match "}" t t nil 2)
  (replace-match "{" t t nil 1))
```

Comment: I tried that, but gave up when the function started getting ugly. If I can't find any other solutions, I may either do that, or live with the cursor moving.

Comment: See revised answer for a fairly neat way to do it.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the revised info. I'll see if I can get a less horrible function using that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  Mine seemed to be resolved by saving `(point)` to variable `p` before replacing, then calling `(goto-char p)` at the end of the function.

Comment: Sensible way to approach it. The only trouble is, the replacement will possibly change the number of characters before the cursor (do -> {), which may or may not require subtracting 1 from p. There should be similar logic at the end. Ditto the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (copy-marker (point) t), which will keep a pointer with the property that when something is inserted at its position, it moves to **after** the new text, rather than staying *before* the new text.