# Emacs lisp : keep cursor position when replacing buffer content

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to fix an issue on in the [web-beautify](https://github.com/yasuyk/web-beautify/issues/11) package.

An elisp function uses an external tool to reformat the content of the buffer.
It then does the following, to try and keep the cursor position :

```
(let ((p (point)))
   (save-excursion
     (with-current-buffer (current-buffer)
       (erase-buffer)
       (insert-buffer-substring outputbuf)))
   (goto-char p)
   ...
```

If any line is added before the point, the `(goto-char p)` can cause the buffer to scroll erratically.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9527449/77804), I tried replacing `p` with `(create-marker (point) t)` ; It does seem to handle text added at the beginning of the buffer better, in general ; however in this case, it does not work at all (presumably because the content of the buffer is completely replace.)

How would you attack this ?

Comment: If the tool only adds/removes whitespace, you could count the number of non-whitespace characters between the start of the buffer and point, and then move that many non-whitespace characters into the buffer after replacing the contents.

Comment: Do you mean counting the non-whitespaces in the buffer *before* replacement ?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way I can think of to preserve the position of point in a way that makes sense to the user.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there can be a fully general answer to this question.  The notion of the place in the new text which corresponds to a particular spot in the original text completely depends on our *human* understanding of what the text is and how it's modified and what matters and what doesn't.

So you need to look at the kind of changes operated by the external tool and try to figure out a way to find what you consider to be the corresponding spot.  E.g. if the tool doesn't add/remove lines, then you can preserve the line-position, on the contrary if the tool only adds/removes lines then you can look at the text surrounding point and try to find it again in the new text.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `replace-buffer` should do the trick.

Source: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47889/10669